# How do I remove the hamburger menu from the title bar and apply the command to a button on my form in CodenameOne

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I have been working on my App and so far have implemented the facebook-like side menu. My problem is that in my App, I don't use the form's default Title bar, and the hamburger only displays in the title bar above my custom title area. How do i assign the hamburger to a button on my form and please how do I style the background of the side menu. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation of the side menu in Codename One is based on the `MenuBar` class and hence integrates directly to the add command/remove command. It won't work properly with a none standard title.

However, the code is relatively simple and you can just use that:
http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/source/browse/trunk/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/ui/SideMenuBar.java and adapt it to your needs. A menu bar in this code is just a form with a very specific transition type.

Customizing the background and components in the side menu bar is pretty easy and you have several UIID's and styles. Specifically the background can be customized via the UIID `SideNavigationPanel`.

Comment: Thank you Shai, so it's not possible to remove the hamburger image from the title? I also would want to set the sidemenu for only certain forms and other forms use the theme native constant. Can you show me some code to achieving this?

Comment: Just remove the command behavior definition you have in the theme or don't invoke setCommandBehavior. If you write your own side menu it should be pretty easy to do that.